# Python 3.6.5 Pip 9.0.1 to 10 Windows 10 no Root

Tags: python-3.x, pip

**Setup:**

My admin installed python into the root dir **I don't have admin rights** (Program Files), I copied it into my user path (Roaming Dir) and added the user path to the %PATH% variable. My local dir is before the root dir in the %PATH% variable. This allowed me to install packages in python from importing pip (`pip.main(['install','--user','package']`).

**Challenge:**

It appears that as pip v9.0.1 depreciated it no longer plays nicely with pypi -- it'll download the files, but can't install them. Throwing the following error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding'`

**Research:**

The prevailing solution here on S/O is to upgrade pip. I can't install pip to the root dir, so instead I installed it to my local path.

**Question:**

How can I get python to use my local pip version first?

Comment: just use `virtualenv`

Comment: @AzatIbrakov you can't setup a virtual environment w/ vnev w/out root access, and the issue I'm having is I can't install packages.

Comment: can you ask admin to install `venv` then?

Comment: No, for arguments sake there is no admin access

Comment: how are you installing `pip` locally? where it is located?

Comment: I install it into my roaming dir, I install it in python by importing pip @AzatIbrakov

Comment: what exact version of Python are you using?

Answer (score -1):

you can install the Conda management system (link [here](http://environment%20management%20system). Go for Miniconda if you want to start from a minimal setup, without the bunch of packages you get with Anaconda but you may not need).

Just follow the wizard to set it as default installation (if you don't have root privileges you'll have to perform the installation under a user-writable folder).

Comment: I don't have root/admin access -- I can't install anything

Comment: yes, you can. From the guide (https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html): "NOTE: You do not need administrative or root permissions to install Anaconda if you select a user-writable install location"

Comment: My profile is located on the network drive, I can't even download Anaconda installer w/out admin rights. @Batsu